# How to resolve conflict in GitLab using GitShell or GitHub Desktop

Tags: java, github, gitlab, git-shell

I am pretty new to GitLab because we just moved to it from `ClearCase`. I Cannot merge some changes into my remote then to my local repo because the GitHub Desktop says that there are some conflicts. I have been looking around to find a simple solution for this in order to view the conflicting file. I got quite a few changes in my local too so I don't want to play around too much with the unfamiliar Git commands because I don't want to loose any of my changes. Is there simple way to find out which file is causing the conflict. I used `git status` and it says that my local branch is up to date.

I am a little lost. Can someone give me some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly then

> Is there simple way to find out which file is causing the conflict?

Then try this command `git ls-files -u` will give a list of conflicts from Git.

Also you want to save your local changes then use `git stash` if you don’t want to do a commit of half-done work and you can get back to this point later by using `git stash apply`

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for?Clean solution. So I got conflicts in two of the files and this command clearly indicated those two files. What I did was I saved my changes somewhere and did the merge. Once I got the new code in my local I put in my in my changes and it's working absolutely fine. Thanks you so much Zachi.

Comment: @Mike glad it helped! happy Git_ing :)